# Is my described case of waswas haram?

Tags: halal-haram

I have a question about waswas. I heard that if you give into waswas then it’s haram. So in my case is this haram: I think of waswas and then waswas comes to me. Does that mean giving into waswas?

If not what does it mean by giving into waswas?

Edit: when I say I think of waswas I just think of it in general or I think of the topic that gets whispered to my ear then those whispers reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Salam 'alayk

When people say "giving into waswaas is haram" it means it's haram to act upon a waswaas such as when you Shaytaan urges you to commit a sin, he will whisper into you this thought, so acting upon that reccomendation by Shaytaan is haram, but merely having the thoughts/waswaas is out of your control so there is nothing wrong in that and it's normal.